# Ingenico API : ACCESS_TO_MERCHANT_NOT_ALLOWED

Tags: php, api, authentication

I'm currently trying to make Ingenico API works with my php project.

I generated my api key and secret on my test account and tried to create à session using this endpoints : `'/v2/'.$merchantID.'/sessions'` merchantID beeing my PSPID account.

here's my code so far :

```
$apiKeyId = 'myAPIKey';
$apiSecret = 'myAPISecret';
$apiEndpoint = 'https://payment.preprod.direct.ingenico.com';

$hash = array(
    'POST',
    'application/json',
    gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'),
    '/v2/'.$merchantID.'/sessions\n'
);

$headers = [
    "Authorization: GCS v1HMAC:".$apiKeyId.":".base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', implode("\n", $hash), $apiSecret))
];

// Setup cURL
$ch = curl_init($apiEndpoint.'/v2/'.$merchantID.'/sessions');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
));

// Send the request
$res = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if($res === FALSE)
    die(curl_error($ch));

// Decode the response
$responseData = json_decode($res, TRUE);

// Close the cURL handler
curl_close($ch);

echo json_encode($responseData);
exit;
```

It's suppose to be the equivalent of their 'minimal' example from this url :
https://support.direct.ingenico.com/documentation/api/authentication , authenticate without SDK

Whatever i try, i get the following return :

```
{
    "errorId": "b498810b-beda-4d50-8ba7-7d3da816b40e",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "9007",
            "id": "ACCESS_TO_MERCHANT_NOT_ALLOWED",
            "category": "DIRECT_PLATFORM_ERROR",
            "message": "ACCESS_TO_MERCHANT_NOT_ALLOWED",
            "httpStatusCode": 403
        }
    ],
    "status": 403
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _When something is wrong with your credentials you will get a 403 response. This could happen when you are trying to access a merchantId that is not linked to your account._ - source [test connection](https://epayments-api.developer-ingenico.com/s2sapi/v1/en_US/dotnet/services/testconnection.html?paymentPlatform=ALL#services-testconnection)

Comment: You sure you got the right merchant ID ?

Comment: Yes, my merchantID is ok, i confirmed it with the ingenico support, there is nothing wrong with my api keys nor my merchantID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after several days of research, INGENICO used a library called cryptoJS to encrypt the signature.

Maybe this informations will help others people in the future.

Comment: The official SDK just uses `base64_encode` and `hash_hmac`: https://github.com/Ingenico/direct-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/Ingenico/Direct/Sdk/RequestHeaderGenerator.php. The difference between that class and your code is that the SDK uses `true` as final argument to `hash_hmac`, and you use the default of `false`.

Comment: Also, make sure the date used in the signature is exactly the same as the date header added by cURL. If possible, set the date explicitly. That's what the SDK does (same class): `$requestHeaders['Date'] = $this->getRfc161Date();`.